# Socket.io - Server Relaying, client-to-client messaging

Tags: sockets, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Socket.IO, I'm either over-thinking it, or I just don't understand how it works. Probably the latter.
Can someone please help me out.

I am seeing examples all over the place that talk about emitting , back to the sender, broadcasting to all clients, or broadcasting to all clients but the sender.

What is not clear is where this is all happening, server or client, or both?
My main questions are:

- Does a server have to relay everything to all clients?
- Can a client
  send a message directly to all other clients (without the server
  having to relay it)
- Can a client send a message directly to specific
  client?

I would be **very very** grateful for any help in clarifying this to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. The server does not have to relay everything to the clients. That is where you have the option to emit back to the sender, all clients, or all clients but the sender.
2. No, the client always sends a message to the server.
3. No, same reason as above -- you could send a message from original client, to server, to intended specific client, but you would have to hop through the server.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I understand what you are saying however I can't find any demos or examples that show clients emitting without the server having to parrot it, it just seems so redundant.
 
**Server.js**
[http://socket.io/get-started/chat/](http://socket.io/get-started/chat/)
 
`io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});`

Comment: That is the purpose of the server in this situation, though -- to relay messages from one client to others. Admittedly, the examples given are very simple (on purpose), which is probably why they seem so redundant. Even peer to peer connections typically require a central server of some sort for client registration and discovery (or at least, that's my understanding of it). Take a look at peerjs if you want to try bypassing the typical server.